# Ошибка 1142 при вставке данных в таблицу MySQL

Tags: mysql, триггер

При выполнении вставки данных в таблицу я получаю ошибку:

> Error Code: 1142
>   TRIGGER command denied to user 'root'@'%' for table 'import_files_log'

При этом и мой текущий пользователь, и DEFINER триггера, связанного с таблицей, оба обладают правами суперюзера. Так, запрос

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

выдаёт результат

> user@%,

и триггер, связанный с таблицей, содержит строку:

> /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'%' */

В то время как таблица `mysql.user` содержит следующие записи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём тогда причина ошибки?

Comment: Проверьте вывод команды `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';`

Comment: Вот он: GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*...' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: Как и ожидалось, привилегии `TRIGGER` нет

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, спасибо, действительно, причина была в этом! Если напишете это как ответ, обязательно приму :)

Comment: Оформил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите все права для пользователя `'root'@'%'` командой

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';
```

у Вас не будет хватать привилегии TRIGGER. Добавьте ее командой

```
GRANT TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

или выдайте все права

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```